# Can't run java when trying to download Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm working with a Scala project and am trying to get IntelliJ to work with it.  (If it makes a difference, I've gotten it to work before.  But my machine died and had to be replaced, and this is the first time I've tried to use Scala since reinstalling IntelliJ on the new machine.)  The machine is running Linux.

I've gotten the banner that says "No Scala SDK in module", and I selected "Setup Scala SDK"; Create; Download; Version 2.11.11; OK.  But I get the message

> Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/tmp/sbt-project"): error=2,
>   No such file or directory

Why is it looking in that directory (which does not exist on my machine)?  It's possible there are some settings that got copied over from my previous machine.  If so, where would I find and fix the setting?

How do I get past this problem?

**Note:** In a desperate attempt to work around the error, I created /tmp/sbt-project and symlinked the Java binaries into it.  When I tried again, I got the same error except it said `in directory "/tmp/sbt-project1"`.  I tried creating /tmp/sbt-project1 as a symlink, and when I retried, it said `in directory "/tmp/sbt-project2"`.  What's going on?

Comment: It might be useful to add more information about your environment, e.g. `javac -version`.

Comment: javac -version is 1.8.0_172, but will IntelliJ use "javac" or "java" from the same $PATH as when I run from the command line?

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set on your system?

Comment: Hi @ajb, you can check this blog if this can help with your issue. https://dotnetvibes.com/2018/01/03/intellij-idea-error-cannot-run-program-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: @occasionalvisitor My JDK was already set up.  I don't think that blog applies to this problem.

Comment: @Harald It wasn't set, so perhaps that was the problem.  However, I got around it before I saw your comment, by downloading the Scala binaries separately and using "Browse" instead of "Download" to do the Scala SDK setup.  So at this point it would be hard to tell if that fixes the problem.  Maybe it will help someone else reading this question, though.

Answer (score 0):

In short: I have no idea why you and I both experienced this problem, but these steps remedied the situation for my particular case (no guarantees but maybe it will help you too)

1. Close Intellij
2. Likely in your home directory, backup and remove the .Idea* directory containing your personal settings
3. Open Intellij and at the welcome screen choose `Do not import settings`
4. Using the guided installation, ensure the "Featured" plugin, Scala, is installed
5. Reopen your project and when you setup the Scala SDK, miraculously a pre-existing version of Scala SDK should exist from the "Ivy" repository (I tested this on a fresh VM of Lubuntu)
6. After selecting the (likely outdated) Scala SDK, again go to Project Settings and under Global Libraries click the `+` symbol to add the latest Scala SDK.
7. Miraculously once again, you will see now both the SDK version from before and the latest version of Scala - choose that one and done!

Notes:

- Before running those above steps, I tried the same things you did on the VM, possibly caching install versions I wasn't even aware of that later became available once I resetup Intellij.
- The reason I suspect this worked is because I thought I would save myself time by copying the .Idea* directory *from a different machine* and using that - many paths were different! So likely I just disabled features with broken paths from my other machine
- Even though I never needed to press the "Download" button, if I do I still get that same error! So I guess all this did was bypass manually downloading the SDK like you had to do...
- My setup:

  - OS: `Lubuntu-16.04.3-lts`
  - Intellij Version: 
    `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
    Build #IC-181.5087.20, built on May 16, 2018
    JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
    JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
    Linux 4.13.0-43-generic`
  - echo $PATH
    `/home/e/tools/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/home/e/bin:/home/e/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: I still got 'No such file or directory' prompt in step 6, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when installing Scala by IntelliJ.

You can choose to install Scala mannually.

For example, install Scala follow this tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-scala-on-centos-7

Then use **Browse** when selecting Scala SDK. Choose your directory, e.g. `/usr/share/scala/`

You can use Scala in IntelliJ now.